# What makes Cardano different from other cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin and Dogecoin?

Tags: decentralization

From Wikipedia, cryptocurrency is:

> A cryptocurrency, crypto-currency, or crypto is a digital asset designed to work
> as a medium of exchange wherein individual coin ownership records are stored in a
> ledger existing in a form of a computerized database using strong cryptography to
> secure transaction records, to control the creation of additional coins, and to
> verify the transfer of coin ownership.

This applies to Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies.

So, what makes Cardano different?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. However, it is better if we wait for other community members to come up with a much better answer. Just my humble suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Cardano is classified as a third-generation Cryptocurrency due to the following reasons.

1. **Smart Network**  It is almost impossible to have smart transactions in Bitcoin Network. In Cardano, the transactions will be programmable.
2. **Energy Consumption** Cardano uses the Proof of stake concept for evolving consensus with respect to the selection of valid transactions. This reduces energy consumption for running the network by approximately a million times. Cardano can be run using embedded processors.
3. **Research** Cardano is an organically evolving financial operating system with more than 100 peer-reviewed academic research papers. While Bitcoin protocol is more or less frozen since the mechanism for adaptation does not exist.
4. **Governance**  There is a established mechanism for governance financed by the protocol itself through treasury for continuous research, management, and guidance of the project by its stakeholders. No such mechanism exists in Bitcoin.
5. **Bottom-up Approach**   Cardano aims to have practical utility in the lives of millions of people neglected by the traditional financial system. While Bitcoin is just a store of value.

I am avoiding mentioning the other project being compared in the question since I feel it's a meme made with the purpose to discredit cryptocurrency and does not deserve an effort for answers.